# Asp panel Default button fire only specific key enter press

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp panel in page which have many input filed like(textbox,checkbox,select etc)
and two button one for saving(btnSave) the form and the second is for cancel(btnCancel) purpose, and the btnSave is the default button of panel.

The problem occurs when the cancel key get the focus and user press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, then the default key of asp panel which in this case is save button fire.

```
<asp:panel DefabultButton="save">
   <asp:textbox id="someid" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
   <asp:textbox id="someid2" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
   <asp:textbox id="someid3" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
   <asp:textbox id="someid4" runat="server"></asp:textbox>

   <asp:button id="btnSave" run="server" value="Save" />
   <asp:button id="btnCancel" run="server" value="Cancel" />

</asp:panel>
```

is there any way to prevent the default key firing on cancel key <kbd>Enter</kbd> press.

Comment: In that case, the user should use the space bar instead of the enter key. I guess you could change it with javascript though...

Comment: is there any way to get the cancel key in any page using javascript or jquery. where cancel button having attribute causesvalidation sets to false.(what kind of code generated by asp for a button that has attribute causesvalidation sets to false).

Comment: This part is spelled wrong **DefabultButton="save"**. It should be **DefaultButton="save"**.